# What does it mean when a viewmodel contains [required]?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My project has viewmodels labeled like this:

```
public class locViewModel  {

[Required]
public string City { get; set; }
}
```

If the view does not set a value then how can I detect this? Is this how the [required] works? Also what other kind of tags can I add to fields in a viewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that for validation purposes you can do numerous things.  For instance, in a View you can have client validation enabled and the form will not submit unless the control that is populating that property has data entered into it.

With a property with the `Required` attribute, and a `Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.City, "City is required")` you can notify the user on the client-side that it is a required field.

Here is a [Great Resource](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/04/30/eagerly-performing-asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-client-side-validation.aspx) on unobtrusive validation, and an in depth explanation of what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you explain "the form will not submit" ?   Thanks

Comment: @RichardM what I mean by that is that you won't have a POST until all `Required` fields have data.  The JavaScript/jQuery will prevent the POST and display that validation message above for the user to be notified they need to input that data.

Comment: @RichardM If the you not entered the city postback always be false